# Linux/C: Process with a child both hangs after adding waitpid

Tags: c, linux, pipe

Consider the following piece of code, which does:

- Fork a child, creating a pipe. The child will redirect the standard input to the pipe, and then read from the standard input (aka from the pipe).
- The child waits for the word "close" to be written to stdin (the pipe). When that happens, the child prints something and `exit(0)`.
- The parent waits for input; any single character suffices. When that happens, the parent writes `"close"` to its end of the pipe and then the parent returns.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void child()
{
    char cmd[16] = {'\0'};
    int B = 0;

    do {
        B = scanf("%s", cmd);
    } while (B == 1 && strcmp(cmd, "close") != 0);

    printf("Exit child for command %s.\n", cmd); fflush(stdout);
    exit(0);
}

struct forked_t
{
    pid_t pid;
    int fd;
};

struct forked_t fork_child()
{
    struct forked_t ret = { -1, -1 };

    int pipe_fds[2];
    int err = pipe(pipe_fds); if (err == -1) return ret;
    pid_t pid_child = fork(); if (pid_child == -1) return ret;

    if (pid_child == 0) {
        close(pipe_fds[1]);
        dup2(pipe_fds[0], 0);
        close(pipe_fds[0]);
        child();
    } else
        close(pipe_fds[0]);

    ret.pid = pid_child;
    ret.fd = pipe_fds[1];
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    struct forked_t child = fork_child();

    if (child.fd <= 0 || child.pid <= 0) {
        printf("Error creating child.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    char c;
    int B = scanf("%c", &c);
    B = write(child.fd, "close", 5); if (B != 5) return -1;
    //waitpid(child.pid, NULL, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Executing it gives:

```
$ ./wait
c
Exit child for command close.
```

However, if I uncomment the line "waitpid" after the write, both parent and child freeze. I don't know why. Based on extra `printf`s added to the child, it looks like the child has not received the write operation, which is weird.

Is adding `waitpid` after writting `close` to the pipe causes the pipe contents not to be sent to the child somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
B = scanf("%s", cmd);
```

will block, attempting to consume as many non-whitespace characters as it can from the standard input. It will only stop when it encounters a whitespace character (as defined by [`isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace)), or when `stdin` reaches end-of-file (or an error occurs).

(*It is for reasons like this that an unbound `%s` specifier makes `scanf` [as dangerous as `gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2505965). Always use a field-width specifier (e.g., `%15s`) to prevent buffer overflows.*)

When the parent exits, the last open write-end of the pipe is also closed, and thus the child sees end-of-file on its read-end of the pipe.

If the parent instead blocks on `waitpid`, without having closed its write-end of the pipe, the processes will [deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).

Use `close(child.fd);` after the `write` in the parent, before `waitpid`.

Alternatively, writing the *six* bytes of `"close "` to the pipe with `strncmp(cmd, "close", 5)` in the child, and then waiting without closing the write-end of the pipe in the parent process highlights the issue.

---

Note that a parent process should always `wait` for its child processes, otherwise you are creating [*orphan processes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process).

Comment: I have a `while` in the child that only exits if "close" is read. If the write is actually performed, the child won't "hang on scanf" because it won't do another iteration.

Comment: @ABu That call to `scanf` will not stop when only the five bytes of `"close"` are read - it needs a sixth, whitespace byte, or for `stdin` to be marked end-of-file.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. `scanf` blocks without a space because of `%s`. Consider to mark in bold **non-writespace**.